# factanal package in R with correlation matrix but no number of observations, why still output?

Tags: r

When I use factanal in R to deal with a correlation matrix but no nobs, still give outputs, but p-value increases with number of factors

M is a correlation matrix:

> ```
>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
>  [1,] 1.00 0.37 0.34 0.40 0.27 0.59 0.09 0.25 0.27  0.22  0.26
>  [2,] 0.37 1.00 0.27 0.25 0.38 0.46 0.10 0.26 0.29  0.22  0.24
>  [3,] 0.34 0.27 1.00 0.36 0.28 0.33 0.18 0.32 0.38  0.29  0.30
>  [4,] 0.40 0.25 0.36 1.00 0.22 0.35 0.08 0.31 0.26  0.25  0.20
>  [5,] 0.27 0.38 0.28 0.22 1.00 0.29 0.16 0.14 0.18  0.15  0.22
>  [6,] 0.59 0.46 0.33 0.35 0.29 1.00 0.08 0.27 0.24  0.28  0.26
>  [7,] 0.09 0.10 0.18 0.08 0.16 0.08 1.00 0.19 0.13  0.22  0.17
>  [8,] 0.25 0.26 0.32 0.31 0.14 0.27 0.19 1.00 0.36  0.36  0.40
>  [9,] 0.27 0.29 0.38 0.26 0.18 0.24 0.13 0.36 1.00  0.30  0.60
> [10,] 0.22 0.22 0.29 0.25 0.15 0.28 0.22 0.36 0.30  1.00  0.25
> [11,] 0.26 0.24 0.30 0.20 0.22 0.26 0.17 0.40 0.60  0.25  1.00
> ```

```
factanal(covmat = M, factors = 2)`$` gives:
```

The degrees of freedom for the model is 44 and the fit was 0.6277

```
factanal(covmat = M, factors = 3) will gives:
```

The degrees of freedom for the model is 34 and the fit was 0.2355

```
 factanal(covmat = M, factors = 4) gives :
```

The degrees of freedom for the model is 17 and the fit was 0.0747

```
factanal(covmat = M, factors = 5)  gives :
```

The degrees of freedom for the model is 10 and the fit was 0.033

This is contradicts with our common sense that the more the factors, less significant the test should become.

Maybe it have some kinds of default of nobs?

Comment: Can you show an example of where you give a matrix but no n.obs and still get a statistic and p-value out please. You would expect to get dof as its based on the correlation matrix.

Comment: I guess I was wrong the output is not a test. _fit_ is 0.033, not _pvalue_. My mistake. factanal cannot use a test and help us determine the number of factors to keop.

Comment: Even if you have n, I would suggest not using the chisq test to determine the number of factors to keep.I would suggest using Glorfeld's adaptation to Horn's parallel analysis, and then assess the fit with the standard statistics, of say the optimum and ± 1 factors on each side (ie 3,4,5 factors if 4 is optimum)